# FastAPI Upload to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, fastapi

I've been scratching my head on this for days now. I still couldn't solve the problem. Basically, I just wanted to put a CSV file in a LocalStack S3, and I can't get it working.

Here's the snippet of my code:

**api.py**

```
from files import s3, AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME, upload_file_to_bucket
    
@router.post('/api/customer/generate/upload',
                 name='Upload CSV to AWS S3 Bucket',
                 status_code=201)
    async def post_upload_user_csv(file_obj: UploadFile = File(...)):
        upload_obj = upload_file_to_bucket(s3_client=s3(),
                                           file_obj=file_obj.file,
                                           bucket=AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
                                           folder='CSV',  # To Be updated
                                           object_name=file_obj.filename)
        if upload_obj:
            return JSONResponse(content="Object has been uploaded to bucket successfully",
                                status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                                detail="File could not be uploaded")
```

**files.py**

```
import os
import boto3
import logging

from botocore.client import BaseClient
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')
AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY')
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME')


def s3() -> BaseClient:
    client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                          aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
                          endpoint_url='http://localhost:4566/')  # Use LocalStack Endpoint

    return client


def upload_file_to_bucket(s3_client, file_obj, bucket, folder, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param s3_client: S3 Client
    :param file_obj: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param folder: Folder to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """
    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_obj

    # Upload the file
    try:
        # with open("files", "rb") as f:
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(file_obj, bucket, f"{folder}/{object_name}")
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

The problem is that s3_client needs to open the file in binary mode first before I can upload it to s3 bucket. However, this can't be done directly and the file needs to be saved temporarily on the FastAPI server but I really don't want to do that for obvious reasons.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: could write the file to io.BytesIO first?

Comment: @fishstix44

Sorry for the confusion. 

Please correct me I got something wrong with my logic. Of course, writing the file to a variable is very much preferred rather than saving it on a disk. From what I understand, UploadFile is a file-like object, meaning it's stored temporarily on the memory and not directly on the disk. What I'm trying to do is chunk by chunk or asynchronously upload the provided file directly to S3, whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

Can you show the error first?
Bassicly. I have done it before. Upload directly a file from the front-end to aws-s3. Can you try to add `ContentType` to upload_fileobj. Here is my code

```
 content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(fpath)[0]
 s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(Fileobj=file, Key=file_path,
                                          ExtraArgs={"ACL": "public-read",
                                                     "ContentType": content_type})
```

another way. You should try to convert files to io.BytesIO

```
 def s3_upload(self, file, file_path, bucket_name, width=None, height=None, make_thumb=False, make_cover=False):
    s3 = boto3.resource(service_name='s3')
    obj = BytesIO(self.image_optimize_from_buffer(file, width, height, make_thumb, make_cover))
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(Fileobj=obj, Key=file_path,
                                          ExtraArgs={"ACL": "public-read", "ContentType": file.content_type})
    return f'https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{file_path}'
```